# Is Magsafe strain relief covered by warranty?

Tags: magsafe, charger

I own a macbook 2012 and the cable snapped due to strain relief. I have **not** wrapped the cable around the charger box tight considering this could happen but it did anyways.

Is this covered by the warranty?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. Because my computer was more than 1 year off the shelf, it was out of warranty; they charged me $60 rather than the $80 shelf price for a new Magsafe charger. Hurry to Apple Church before your warranty expires!
Their Support page for this: http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS4127